# WcfTestClient not opening when running a simple webservice program using c# instead opens a webpage - New to c# programming

Tags: c#, web-services, wcftestclient

I am trying to run a simple webservice for random numbers using c#. When running the program, it opens a webpage instead of running the WCF Test Client. I have a VS 2019 installed. I also see the wcftestclient.exe in the folder. 

Please help me if I am missing any setup/ where to enable it so that it runs in the wcftestclient. 

Thanks in Advance.

1. I tried to as `/client:"wcftestclient.exe"` in application arguments in **project properties -> debug**
2. added project extensions as below in .csproj,

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" 
                          Version="2.1.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ProjectExtensions>
        <VisualStudio>
            <FlavorProperties GUID="{123c5851-25df-10da-9384-00011b846f00}">
                <WebProjectProperties> 
                    <EnableWcfTestClientForSVCDefaultValue>
                        True
                    </EnableWcfTestClientForSVCDefaultValue>
                </WebProjectProperties>
            </FlavorProperties>
        </VisualStudio>
    </ProjectExtensions>
</Project>
```

3. tried to disable launch browser in **proj properties-> debug**

```
namespace SampleWebServiceasp
{
    class RandomNumberGeneratorService
    {
        public NumberModel GetRandomNumbers()
        {
            var random = new Random();
            var numberobject = new NumberModel
            {
                RandomNumber1 = random.Next(-500, 5000),
                RandomNumber2 = random.Next(-500, 5000),
                RandomNumber3 = random.Next(-500, 5000)
            };
            return numberobject;
        }

    }
}
```

```
namespace SampleWebServiceasp.Models
{
    public class NumberModel
    {
        public int RandomNumber1 { get; set; }
        public int RandomNumber2 { get; set; }
        public int RandomNumber3 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Expected to run it in wcftestclient and it opens a webpage

Comment: Try starting debugging with an .svc file open as the active file in VS.

Answer (score 3):

Before you start running or debugging select the service svc.cs file in "Solution Explorer"

[image: Solution Explorer]

As indicated in the notes for the default wcf template

> // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select Service1.svc or Service1.svc.cs at the Solution
>   Explorer and start debugging.

Answer (score 3):

For me, "Windows Communication Foundation" component was not installed in Visual Studio. Installing it solved.